# CS (Condition Zero and 1.6) lagging horribly even on Wired connection

Tags: counter-strike, counter-strike-condition-zero

I just got my new Internet connection installed, 512 kbps download. I know that's damn slow, but should be able to run CS right? According to speedtest my latency is 3 on Wired and 7 on WiFi. I was using Wired when I tried to play CS. My latency was about 45~50 but my game lagged horribly.

Is there any way to get rid of the lag? Or is my internet's speed isn't good enough? I'm running CS at the lowest resolution.

BTW my PC specs-
Intel i3 M350 (First Gen)
Intel HD Graphics 1696 MB (again, First Gen)
6 GB RAM
500 GB HDD
Windows 8.1 PRO x64
Its a laptop, not to mention quite old.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about tech support for trying to run a game on a system that doesn't meet the minimum system requirements.

Comment: @Frank Dude, its nothing like that... I asked the question on suspicion of my internet connection, and regarding system requirements if you compare my system does meet them, now whether they are old and integrated etc is an entirely different thing.

Comment: Your CPU meets the requirements, but I don't think your GPU does. Tech support is hard enough to troubleshoot, even when you do meet the requirements. It's exponentially harder when you don't.

Comment: @Frank I completely understand bro... running that GPU is a pain I go through daily, hopefully not for much longer now..

Comment: @Frank, the GPU should be fine. True, it's integrated. That does send up flares. But the games are fairly old, in comparison.[According to gamesystemrequirements.com](http://gamesystemrequirements.com/game/counter-strike-condition-zero), **the minimum GPU for CS:Condition Zero is a card with a meager 16mb of RAM**. Integrated cards are fairly on point with supporting.older games like this. Voting to leave open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's your problem

> Intel i3 M350 (First Gen)
>
> HD Graphics 1696 MB (again, First Gen)

Forget the internet, start an offline game with/without bots (you don't need the bots for this) See if it lags there as well ... Type in net_graph 1 in the console to see your FPS in the game (works off and online, not cheating) If you are lagging when playing offline, then it's not the internet that's at fault.

Please note that it MAY not lag AS MUCH as it does when online, to stress the game, add bots, throw some smokes, if it's smooth and you get goof FPS then it's the internet, if not, it's the machine that requires upgrade.

If it is in fact the internet, there are few things you can do to help yourself:

1. Make sure you are not torenting. Seeding especially, hurts the internet ALOT, so shut down any torrenting clients.
2. Shut down any software you don't need, especially the browser. When I decided It's time to play CS i shut my browser, I also have Team Viewer, and some other programs I'm using. I switch everything off, except Steam ...

To clarify on my first lines: I know that on paper the CPU and the GPU might be good "oh look it has 2GB of video memory although CS requires only 128mb" etc etc ...  I KNOW but not many people realize how bad the Integrated graphics really are, and how much worse the Gen 1 are ....

EDIT: To be honest though Windows 8 and 8.1 are quite optimized for old systems, and the RAM should be more than enough. But as mentioned I strongly believe it's the CPU and GPU that bottlenecks and not the internet.

EDIT2: SpeedTest Latency is different than the one in CS, but 50 is quite fine for multiplayer.

Comment: That's exactly what I guessed. My old CPU plus the integrated GPU is the cause of a lot of problems (I do video editing, Image processing etc as well). And yes it does lag a bit during LAN games, I get roughly 20~30 FPS, it rarely goes above that. Surprisingly FIFA 13 runs better than CS on my PC.

Comment: Also, I'm myself a geeky guy so I already shut down any service that could be using my internet. I optimized my PC as much as I could before running the game. Moreover even if my internet is at fault, is there anything I can do besides getting the speed changed?